# How np.array (or vstack) column slice work?

Tags: python, numpy

Why in:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2 ,3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
t= np.array(([a,b])
print(t[1:])
print(t[:0])
print(t[:1])
print(t[:2])
```

the result of the first column and second column is :

```
[[4 5 6]]
[]
[[1 2 3]]
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

If the array is:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Why then the:

- first row `t[1:]` is not `[4 5 6]` and
- first column `t[:0]` is not `[1, 4]` and
- second column `t[:1]` is not `[2, 5]` and
- second column `t[:3]` is not `[3, 6]`
  ?
  How to conceptualise this?

Comment: `t` is 2d, (2,3). Check its `shape`. All your indexing is on the first dimension, rows. Try `[:,1]`,[1,:] etc if you want : to select a whole row or column.

Comment: Reread The documentation about indexing and slices

Comment: @hpaulj thank you your comment was helpful with mentioning that lack of coma makes the indexing on 1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `t` is a 2-dim array. In this case, `t.shape` should be `(2, 3)`. The first dim `2` is for rows and the second dim `3` is for columns.

Please note that each index should be separated by comma `,`, like `t[0, 1]`. This indicates an element at the first row and the second column.

If you use only one index such as `t[1]`, numpy treats it as an index for rows. So you get identical result by `t[1, :]`.

> - first row t[1:] is not [4 5 6]

This might come from a constraint that `[0:]` and `[1:]` should have similar results. [1:] is just a special case where only one row is selected. `[4 5 6]` can be sliced as `t[1 ,:]`.

> - first column t[:0] is not [1, 4] and

As explained above, when only one index is fed into 2-dim array, the index is treated as for rows. The empty result is because [:0] indicates nothing. You can see similar phenomena with `list(range(0))`.

> - second column t[:1] is not [2, 5] and

If you want to obtain a second column, please type `t[:, 1]`

- second column t[:3] is not [3, 6] ?

-> This should be `t[;, 2]`

Comment: `t[1,:]` and `t[1:,:]` produce similar results, but with a shape difference.

Comment: @hpaulj @dkato 1) But why `t[0:]` produces entire 2d array and `t[1:]` produces only second row? 2) And why `t[2:]` returns empty list `[]` (there is no 3,4,5 etc row)? Shouldn't there be an error about that?

Comment: `t[0:]` returns a set of rows from 0 to end as a 2-dim array. And `t[1:]` returns rows starts from 1 to end. Please use 3x3 array such as `t = [1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7,8,9] ]` and check that `t[1:]` produces 2x3 array.

Comment: @dkato thanks accepted. Please add this comment to the accepted answer